# Solve For X inside arc-cos function (with division)

Tags: equation-solving

Very basic but I've been stuck for more than 12 hours trying to solver this equation

```
20=360/(arccos(X/3200)*2)
```

Can anyone solve X? and explain what exactly you did to solve it so I can learn it.

Thanks.

Comment: This site is for questions about Mathematica(TM), which is a software product. If you have questions about mathematics please post them in http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange and simplify the terms to find $ArcCos[X/3200] = 9$ and then take the cosine of each side to find $X = 3200 Cos[9]$.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks